# Android: Determining image size for image view

Tags: android, picasso

I tried looking up for an answer on SO but couldn't find any.

I want to load an image from a url and display it on my image view. For the same, I am using Picasso but I am confused how should I go about resizing it. What width and height arguments should I pass it?

To ensure optimality (least size, best quality), what parameters do I need?
 1. Original image width (px)
 2. Original image height (px)
 3. Screen dpi (ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/etc)
 4. Screen size in px / inches ? (Do I need this?)

My image view layout is set to  android:layout_width="match_parent" and android:layout_height="wrap_content. Do I need to change them as well?

Please consider both landscape and portrait orientation of images. Thanks.

Comment: Usually, you set the `ImageView` to be the size that you want. Picasso will then resize as appropriate to fit the `ImageView`.

Comment: But since different images will have different sizes, what size should the layout be fixed to ?

Comment: I assumed that you had more consistent images, sorry. Whether you control the size of the `ImageView` or the size of the image at runtime will not strictly matter. However, the optimal size is whatever your UI needs it to be, perhaps taking aspect ratio into account. Somewhere, you need some constraints (e.g., the image will be only such-and-so wide, and then however tall it needs to be).